# Python, how to get first list element in reversed order?

Tags: python

Please consider below code, I want to reversed the first two elements. That is target string is  "abcd", the first two elements is "ab", and i need "ba". How can i use below code to do it? (I know i have alternative ways to do, but how to do in below way?)

```
    r = "abcd"
    t = r[1:0:-1]
    print(t)
    # print b
```

Another way:

```
    r = "abcd"
    t = r[1:-1:-1]
    print(t)
    # print NOTHING!
```

Comment: `’abcd’[1::-1]`

Comment: @jonrsharpe the top answer in that question actually does not explain what happens when you include `start` and `step`, but leave `stop` blank. The third top answer even gives the *wrong* information (when `step` is negative, as it is here). Is this really a duplicate?

Comment: @JeremyMcGibbon then by all means suggest improvements, but we don’t need a separate new question for every possible use of slicing, that’s why the canonical dupes exist.

Answer (score 3):

You're close! You need to remove the `0` from your indexing expression. Your indexing expression is of the form `start:stop:step`, where stop is *not* included. If you don't put any value for `stop`, then it will continue until the end of the string (in this case, the start of the string, since `step` is negative).

```
r = "abcd"
t = r[1::-1]
print(t)  # prints 'ba'
```

Comment: O thank you. That's working, but considering below case: for a string 'abcdefghijk', for every 4 chars, i need to reversed the first two. How can I do this by without explicit check it is the first char and i should put empty in stop?

Comment: I have add sample code in question, thank you!

Comment: @DingLi do not change questions after receiving answers. Ask the thing you actually want to know to start with.